# How to apply kernel regularization in a custom layer in Keras/TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, regularized

Consider the following custom layer code from a TensorFlow tutorial:

```
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, num_outputs):
    super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
    self.num_outputs = num_outputs

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
                                  shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
                                         self.num_outputs])

  def call(self, input):
    return tf.matmul(input, self.kernel)
```

How do I apply any pre-defined regularization (say `tf.keras.regularizers.L1`) or custom regularization on the parameters of the custom layer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `add_weight` method takes a `regularizer` argument which you can use to apply regularization on the weight. For example:

```
self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
                               shape=[int(input_shape[-1]), self.num_outputs],
                               regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1_l2())
```

Alternatively, to have more control like other built-in layers, you can modify the definition of custom layer and add a `kernel_regularizer` argument to `__init__` method:

```
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, num_outputs, kernel_regularizer=None):
    super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
    self.num_outputs = num_outputs
    self.kernel_regularizer = regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
                                  shape=[int(input_shape[-1]), self.num_outputs],
                                  regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer)
```

With that you can even pass a string like `'l1'` or `'l2'` to `kernel_regularizer` argument when constructing the layer, and it would be resolved properly.